# print xlsx file from command line using ghostscript and libreoffice

Tags: command-line, server, printing, libreoffice, pdf

I have been searching on how to get libreoffice in headless mode to print to a ghostscript PDF file on **Ubuntu Server 12.04**.

Can somebody tell me how to do this or if there is an easier way?

I tried with unoconv but the PDF result didn't look right, I am hoping the ghostscript way prints it directly as it looks in Excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run `libreoffice` in headless mode, but before executing the following command, first quit/close all running Libreoffice instances.

In order to print xlsx files you'll have to install `libreoffice-calc` on your server:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-calc
```

Then the following command will convert your `filename.xlsx` into `filename.pdf` in current folder (`pwd`):

```
libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf <filename.xlsx>
```

and print the document with `lpr`:

```
lpr -U username -P the_printer_name <filename.pdf>
```

---

**Note**: alternatively you could also print-to-file using this command:

```
libreoffice --headless --print-to-file --outdir /tmp <filename.xlsx>
```

Comment: When I enter the first command libreoffice --headless... nothing happens

Comment: no nothing, the command seems like it finishes but does not produce a file

Comment: When I start this first command I get `convert /home/sylvain/Documents/sample.xlsx -> /home/sylvain/Documents/sample.pdf using calc_pdf_Export`

Comment: I don't get anything, no response or errors

Comment: Could you try with another xlsx file? this is the right command to use on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I just created a new xlsx file with data in one cell and still the same

Comment: I have `LibreOffice 4.1.3.2 410m0(Build:2)` (using `libreoffice  --version`)

Comment: Oh, you have to close/quit all Libreoffice instances before executing the command line

Comment: I am using the version from the repo, LibreOffice 3.5, I am on 12.04.4 LTS

Comment: It works for 13.10, some users reported the need of starting the command from the folder where the file is and using sudo. Time to upgrade?

Comment: I just added the libreoffice repo and am now trying with LibreOffice 4.2.2.1.    Now I get Could not find Java Runtime Environment

Comment: I got this too (javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!) but the conversion to pdf succeeded

Comment: strange, I get that error but still no PDF file

Comment: I'd recommend to upgrade to 13.10 as this command seems to not work for everyone on 12.04

Comment: unfortunately it's not that simple as this is a production server

Comment: do you know how I can print to file using ghostscript as an alternative?

Comment: Could you try this before thinking to an alternative: `libreoffice --headless --print-to-file --outdir /tmp <filename.xlsx>`, it will give you a filename.ps in /tmp (in theory). If that works I'll update my answer. again be sure to kill all libreoffice processes running on your server.

Comment: Did you try printing to a file? what's the outcome?

Comment: Hi Sylvain, I tried your command above, unfortunately I do not get a file created, the command runs but nothing

Comment: I only get this kind of behaviour when I have other libreoffice processes running. Did you check that on your server?

Comment: how would I check if either older libreoffice or openoffice processes are running?

Comment: using `pgrep -f libreoffice` and to kill them `pkill -f libreoffice`

Comment: ok I have made sure no libreoffice processes are running but I still get the same, Java Runtime error, command finishes but no output in /tmp

Comment: humm, retested even on a 12.04 system, both commands work, print-to-file and convert-to. The only difference is that in my case I'm running desktop systems.

Comment: I might install a 12.04 system with desktop and see if it works for me, not sure how that will help me on my production server though.

Comment: Could you check that `libreoffice-calc` is installed and if not install it? `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-calc`

Comment: BINGO!  it worked, libreffice-calc wasn't installed

Comment: Excellent, I'll update my answer and add the tag 'server' to your question. Once done please vote and mark it as accepted please

Comment: Perfect, one more thing, do you know why when converting using libreoffice it prints out different to excel, over more pages, can I set default page settings anywhere?

Comment: Usually print settings/print area are defined in the workbook itself. Regarding the export settings to PDF, check this [page](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Tutorials/PDF_export#PDF_Export_Configuration). Please mark my answer as accepted please. You can ask a new question about print settings and the Ask Ubuntu community will do its best to help/assist you.