# How to install Libre Office without GUI

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice

I'm using python and Open Document Files to generate document from CRM then to convert them into PDF format. In this configuration Libre Office is running as a service. That works perfectly on my Desktop development computer without any problem.

The production environment will be a 12.04 Server without GUI and I don't want to be obliged to install Gnome or KDE. Is there a way to have some kind of core installation of Libre Office onto a server without GUI?

Comment: Some `X11` packages will be installed, but you can avoid GNOME/KDE: `apt-get install libreoffice --no-install-recommends  --no-install-suggests`

Comment: also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24096/handle-doc-docx-templates-on-a-headless-server-to-produce-pdfs-preferably-withou

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Libreoffice packages depend on `libreoffice-core`, and `libreoffice-core` alone drags in 90+ packages:

```
# apt-get install libreoffice-core --no-install-recommends
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done    
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core fonts-opensymbol
... snip ...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core fonts-opensymbol
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2-common libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3
  libboost-date-time1.54.0 libcairo2 libclucene-contribs1 libclucene-core1
  libcmis-0.4-4 libcolamd2.8.0 libcups2 libdatrie1 libexttextcat-2.0-0
  libexttextcat-data libfontconfig1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglu1-mesa
  libgraphite2-3 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-common libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b
  libhunspell-1.3-0 libhyphen0 libice6 libicu52 libjasper1 libjbig0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblangtag-common liblangtag1 liblcms2-2 libltdl7
  libmhash2 libmythes-1.2-0 libneon27-gnutls libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpixman-1-0
  libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-common libreoffice-core
  libreoffice-style-galaxy libsm6 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libx11-xcb1
  libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0
  libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3
  libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxslt1.1 libxt6
  libxxf86vm1 libyajl2 lp-solve uno-libs3 ure x11-common
0 upgraded, 91 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 68.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 271 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

So you can't get away with installing any fewer. The `libreoffice` package brings in about 30 more packages. However, if you don't install the integration packages (`libreoffice-gnome`, `libreoffice-kde`), you wouldn't bring in the GNOME/KDE components. The `libreoffice` doesn't depend on these integration packages, so you should be OK with installing just `libreoffice`:

```
apt-get install libreoffice --no-install-recommends
```

Comment: Installing only the core package may not be enough to convert some files to pdf (e.g xlsx). See this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/437331/print-xlsx-file-from-command-line-using-ghostscript-and-libreoffice) where `libreoffice-calc` was required

Comment: @SylvainPineau That was to show that it's not possible to trim it down any further, though I can see that it looks I'm recommend installing only `core`.

Comment: your last edit avoid the confusion, thanks. You have my vote :)

Answer (score 8):

There is now (as of Ubuntu 20.04, possibly earlier) the

```
libreoffice-core-nogui
```

package that further reduces the dependencies. It will remove and replace some modules:

```
libreoffice-base libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-math libreoffice- pdfimport libreoffice-writer
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now.

Comment: This takes about 230M of disk space, instead of about 1G for a standard install.

Answer (score 4):

The package `libreoffice` doesn't depend on Gnome, KDE or Xorg (See [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/precise/libreoffice)).

To keep the installation minimal you can install it with no recommended stuff:

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends install libreoffice
```

Comment: 1 addition `unoconv` is the command line too for conversion ( http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/ )